# Can we use hudson/jenkins to run jobs on Sn Grid or LSF?

Tags: grid, hudson, jenkins

Currently we need to add hosts/nodes and attach a label to them. We give that label while running jobs so that machines can be picked appropriately

In our configuration, Hudson is not a build server but a job dispatch/controller which I use to run regressions tests. I have few hundred testcases. When we run them outside Hudson, we dispatch them on Grid but when we run them Hudson, we can dispatch them only to hosts added in Hudson. We don’t really have good number of nodes available but have good grid support.

Here the plan is to have a Matrix type of project with one axis being the testcases which can run on grid, So I was thinking if there is any mechanism by which I can just give grid as host (may be with some max job limit ‘N’ and/or resource_requirement), Hudson should itself dispatch ‘N’ jobs to grid and then monitor the log and status of jobs

Comment: Did you accomplish this task? I have a similar jenkins jobs where i need to build something on the grid.. Any reference material will help.